# Как отправить запрос используя прокси?

Tags: javascript, request

Здравствуйте, нужно отправить запрос к серверу через прокси. Можно ли это как то сделать и как?

(Не используя node.js)

Comment: Вам же уже блокировали этот вопрос.

Comment: Разве это не http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/445409/181472 ?

Comment: @Visman Я попытался более понятно объяснить

Comment: Я вам ужа там ответил в комментариях. Другого ответа вы все равно не услышите.